Heat equation with Dirichlet boundary condition on a sole point
so I am working with the heat equation: $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(r,t) = D \Delta G(r,t)$ subject to the initial condition $G(r>0,t=0) = 0$ and the boundary condition $G(0,t>0) = 1$. I have not treated before with the heat equation subject to only one boundary condition, where the spatial variable can take any value from $0$ to infinity, instead of being restricted to a closed interval.
I am told that in order to prevent the solution $G$ from diverging as $r \to 0$, I should establish a lower cutoff $a>0$ and set the boundary condition as $G(a,t>0) = 1$. But, why would the solution to the initial problem diverge and why would the lower cutoff prevent this?
I am aware that I am including any attempted resolution to this question of my own, but I am honestly quite lost regarding how to approach this problem and I would appreciate any indications.
P.D.: Should this help, $G$ represents the correlation between the spins of two particles in the plane separated by a certain distance $r$.
Thank you very much.

I meant to say I am not including any attempted resolution

$\Delta^2$ is typically used to denote the biharmonic operator. For the standard Laplacian just use $\Delta$.

We are talking about the heat equation in how many spatial dimensions?

You're right, sorry, I didn't specify. $r$ represents the distance between two particles in the plane.
